# "could not load file or assembly" exception on First Rebuild only

Tags: c#

I have C# project created in VS 2008. I have referenced another DLL to it and kept Copy Local option to true. When I am doing a first rebuild, it fails with "could not load file or assembly" message and then if I build without any changes it builds fine.

In the background, rebuild cleans bin directory and build solution file at this time refrenced DLL gets deleted so it throws exception. On next build referenced DLL remains in bin directory and project builds successfully.

Now I want to know how can I resolve issue and ensure succesful build each time.

Thanks

Comment: Use Project + Project Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If the referenced DLL noes not change (for example if it's a third party component) then a neat trick for this is to change the attributes of the referenced DLL in your BIN folder to read-only and it will not be deleted by the VS Clean function.

Comment: I will try this,but is it generic issue wid VS project build.Don;t we have proper solution/project setting for this?

Comment: I am still struglling with this,latest I have noticed that I have checked "Sign the assembly" and provided .snk file name.If I uncheck this and try to build,rebuild everything works fine. Is it the real cause for this kind of behavior?  I have to have my DLL signed.Please help me to resolve this issue.